# How to transfer multiple value in each textbox in PHP during formload

Tags: php

I have a little  SQL Commands Here

Databasename:Numbers

```
select * from tblstart where id = 1
output = 10
select * from tblstart where id = 2
output = 20
select * from tblstart where id = 3
output = 30
select * from tblstart where id = 4
output = 40
select * from tblstart where id = 5
output = 50
```

How can i transfer this output in textbox during Page Load

```
<input type="text" name="OutputOf10"><br>
<input type="text" name="OutputOf20"><br>
<input type="text" name="OutputOf30"><br>
<input type="text" name="OutputOf40"><br>
<input type="text" name="OutputOf50"><br>
```

Any help would be appreciated TY

Here is the code so far but im getting errors

Here is the php code(Updated)

```
 <?php 

$host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'poi';
try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.'', $db_user, $db_pass);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(name) FROM tblmarker WHERE name = (Robbery)');
  $stmt->execute(array('id'));

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ( count($result) ) { 
    foreach($result as $row) {
      $OutputOf10 = $row['Name'];
      echo '<input type="text" name="OutputOf10" value="'.$OutputOf10.'"><br>';
    }   
  } else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quite a bit of information that would allow us to better help you.

Here's a start:

```
<?php 

$host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'poi';
try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.'', $db_user, $db_pass);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name from tblmarker where id = 112"');
  $stmt->execute(array('OutputOf10' => $id));

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ( count($result) ) { 
    foreach($result as $row) {
      $OutputOf10 = $row['name'];
      echo "<input type="text" name="OutputOf10" id="OutputOf10" value='".$OutputOf10."' ";
    }   
  } else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?> 

<input type="text" name="OutputOf10" value="<?php echo $Outputof10 ?>"><br>
```

To support update:

```
<?php 
$id = 112;
$host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'poi';
try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.'', $db_user, $db_pass);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblmarker WHERE id = :id');
  $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ( count($result) ) { 
    foreach($result as $row) {
      $OutputOf10 = $row['name'];
      echo '<input type="text" name="OutputOf10" value="'.$OutputOf10.'"><br>';
    }   
  } else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: TYSM for this code I will try it and update you later.

Comment: sir what should i add on this because its giving me error  $OutputOf10 = $row['whateveryouaretryingtoselect']; sorry i cant find out

Comment: You should replace $OutputOf10 = $row['whateveryouaretryingtoselect']; with $OutputOf10 = $row[1]; if you are trying to grab the second column from the database. Or if the column name is "Result" you could do $OutputOf10 = $row['Result'];

Comment: `( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\wamp\www\New System CS\brgy_SanBartolome\chart.php on line 106
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0007 375688 {main}( ) ..\chart.php:0
1
( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\New System CS\brgy_SanBartolome\chart.php on line 113
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0007 375688 {main}( ) ..\chart.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: whateveryouaretryingtoselect in C:\wamp\www\New System CS\brgy_SanBartolome\chart.php on line 114
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0007 375688 {main}( ) ..\chart.php:0
`

Comment: Test the following in a script by itself: <?php $id=1; echo $id; ?>

Comment: For the example code I gave you above, I was assuming that you had at least a little knowledge of either PHP or a like language in general. You need to make sure you set the user, pass and database name. Where it says SELECT * FROM Numbers - Numbers is the name of the table. print $row[0]; //This is the first column 
      print $row[1]; //This is the second column is just so you know which row you wish to copy. Set that row to $Outputof10

Comment: do i need to remove this or add rows here?
$OutputOf10 = $row['whateveryouaretryingtoselect'];

Comment: Let's say that the column name in your database that you are trying to select is: "output". Then you should replace that line with: $OutputOf10 = $row['output'];

Comment: Sir my post has just been edited pls take a review if my code is right

Comment: Sir sorry for being noob this is my first time taking php. Now It works TYSM

Comment: I realized there was a syntax error in my original code, but your newly supplied information helped to get the answer you were looking for. You're welcome.

Comment: sir still online? i have a little question im trying to count all the same value in a column where column is = fire here is the code but in mysql its working in php it is not
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(name) FROM tblmarker WHERE name = (Fire)');

Comment: Please post a new question that is detailed in what you are trying to accomplish and I can help you out.

Comment: I just been restricted for asking question, i think its because of posting low questoions. by the way sir i just edit my post. the error is only mysqlcommand within php

Comment: $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(name) FROM tblmarker WHERE name = "Robbery"');

Comment: Sir what am i trying to do is count all the value in my table column that has a value of "Fire" and the textbox will be = "Number of Fire" but i get an error of  Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\New System CS\brgy_SanBartolome\chart.php on line 113